# Add this share not working in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, addthis

I was using add this share plugin.I am creating dynamic data url from ajax call.
My code was:

```
addthis.init();
$('.addthis_sharing_toolbox').attr('data-url',dta);
```

My problem current page url only sharing. I need to send my custom url. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the value of data-url non-empty?

Comment: is it meant to be `dta` and not `data`?

Comment: Whats in `dta`? And why do not use `$('.addthis_sharing_toolbox').data('url');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the variable dta has the URL you'd like to use. Then, follow the instructions on this page to update the URL and title that are shared: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1692927-using-dashboard-configuration-tools-dynamically

Specifically, call the `addthis.layers.refresh()` function.